# How to create a Discrete space with actions as 1 and 3 and skip some in between?

Tags: openai-gym

I am trying to create a subset of the action space. I want it to have actions 1 and 3. How do I do it with Discrete space?

I want something like: `gym.spaces.Discrete(2, start=1, skip=1)`